# SOS: file recover

Tags: c#

Hallo all,
I made some revisions on a c sharp file in visual studio 2008 express, and committed the following actions:
1. open this c sharp file thru notepad,
2. tried to save some modifications in this file while it was opened by the notepad,
3. Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to make a copy to this file
4. closed visual studio 2008 and notepad

Then this c sharp file dissappears! Please help!

John

Comment: Just looked - I definitely haven't got it. Perhaps someone else has?

Comment: When Visual Studio doesn't quite cut it - Notepad.

Answer (score 3):

It's gone forever.  The only thing you can really hope for is to pair the situation with the appropriate whiskey.

If it was months of work down the drain, I would choose Ancient Age out of the plastic bottle.

Answer (score 0):

if you right click in your project and then goto add existing you should be able to re-add it.

As to why it disapears i am not sure ... i guess it may be a file handle problem.

Comment: It dissappears from the explorer.

Comment: visual studio explorer or windows explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a repository, a version control system, or something like that? Otherwise, let your code RIP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it has probably gone forever, but you should be able to recover it from your daily backups. You do take daily backups don't you....?